# Why can't I cook my food in the furnace for Minecraft PE 0.12.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why can't I cook my food in Minecraft PE? It won't always show in the furnace.  It only shows where we are suppose to put the wood, coal, etcetera and when I got a food that isn't cooked yet it doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

First, insert fuel into the bottom input slot. You will not see your raw food as an option in this menu, since it only accepts fuel. After you've put in the fuel, insert your raw food into the top input slot. After 10 seconds, during which you can see the gray arrow turning white, your food will become cooked and move to the output slot on the right.

[image: MCPE Smelting]

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 slots, 2 Inputs and 1 Output, there a 2 inputs one UP and one DOWN, if you click on the bottom slot, you get to the fuel spot, where you put Coal and other burnable stuff. The other slot ontop is where you want to cook, it will take some time to cook. be patient.

Comment: You can put stuff in and then go do other stuff. You dont need to watch it cook.